# Response on the server comes back in Russian language

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, localization, sinatra

I'm using Amazon Web Services, and my instance resides in **us-east-1a** region.

I'm trying to run a script that fetches the torrents against a search. When I locally run the project, everything goes fine; results appear as expected.

But when I run it on server, the result comes back in English plus Russian language. I've doubled checked everything, but why does it produce the different result on Server?

Here is a screen shot of the results on Server environment:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kev8l.png

**Note:** On privacy concern, I can't share my code here.

Comment: without code it's nearly impossible to help. You haven't provided any details that can be used to identify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are making HTTP requests, you may want to ensure you have set your preferred language correctly. For example:

```
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
```